# Value of $t$ minimizing the distance $\lVert a-tb \rVert$

Tags: vectors

The question is

> Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> (a) What value of $t \in \mathbb R$ minimizes the distance $\lVert a-tb \rVert$? (Hint. It’s easier
> to minimize the value of $\lVert a-tb \rVert ^2$.)
>
> (b) What is the minimum distance in (a)?

For part a),

$$\lVert a-tb \rVert ^2 = \lVert a \rVert ^2  -  2t(a \cdot b)  +  t^2\lVert b \rVert ^2.$$

To minimize it, we set the derivative of it with respect to $t$ to $0$. That is,

$$-2(a \cdot b) + 2t\lVert b \rVert ^2=0 \implies t=\frac{a \cdot b}{\lVert b \rVert ^2}.$$

For part b), we substitute the found $t$ value into the original distance formula and get

$$\lVert a - \frac{a \cdot b}{\lVert b \rVert ^2} \cdot b \rVert .\tag{1}$$

But the answer to part b) is given as,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\lVert a \rVert ^2 \lVert b \rVert ^2 - (a \cdot b)^2}{\lVert b \rVert ^2}}.\tag{2}$$

Can you please explain how do we get from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

Comment: It seems that $t$ isn't necessarily in $\mathbb R$ with the way you've solve part (a), assuming that $a,b\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: @boink Yes, I forgot to write a part of the problem statement, I will correct it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the two expressions are the same !

Actually when you replace $t$ by your expression $\frac{a\cdot b}{||b||^2}$ in the developped expression $\lVert a-tb \rVert ^2 = \lVert a \rVert ^2  -  2t(a \cdot b)  +  t^2\lVert b \rVert ^2$, you get the answer $\sqrt{\frac{\lVert a \rVert ^2 \lVert b \rVert ^2 - (a \cdot b)^2}{\lVert b \rVert ^2}}$.

If you really want to find again this answer with yours ($\lVert a - \frac{a \cdot b}{\lVert b \rVert ^2} \cdot b \rVert$), you just need to do the same thing you did at first, which is taking the square and developping, then taking the square root.

Hope it helped.